# If the group $Q$ is $\langle x, y \mid x^{9}=y^{3}=1, x^{y}=x^{-1}\rangle$, what is the subgroup of $Q$ generated by its elements of order dividing 3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $Q=\langle x, y \mid x^{9}=y^{3}=1, x^{y}=x^{-1}\rangle$ and suppose we define a subgroup $‎\Omega‎_1(Q)$ to be the subgroup of $Q$ generated by all elements in $Q$ of order dividing 3.

Can one determine explicitly which elements of $Q$ are in $‎\Omega‎_1(Q)$?

Comment: @EbruArdamoglo Trivially $y$ is one such element, and obviously $z=x^3$ is another.  Can you use the third relation to derive a commutator relation for $z$ and $y$?

Comment: I try to find. Thanks Steven Stadnicki

Comment: (As a slightly further hint, note that unwound, that relation says that $xy=yx^{-1}$.  Now, write $zy=x^3y=xxxy$ and use the commutator to push $y$ past the three copies of $x$.)

Comment: Yes, Why i need commutator of z and y . i see in $Q/Q'$ we need to commutator. [z. y]=1

Comment: This is a PSQ, but it's a tricky question, and the OP is making an effort to solve it.  I did vote to close, but I think the downvotes are excessive.  This isn't being very nice to new users, y'all.

Comment: I do not understand why this question was closed. So, I am voting to re-open.

Comment: @Andreas Caranti: Yes you are right, thanks! I have deleted my comment to avoid causing confusion,

Comment: @DerekHolt, deleting mine in 10, 9, ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be the same thing that @StevenStadnicki is saying, but note that the relation $x^{y}= x^{-1}$ implies $x^{y^{2}} = x$, that is, $x$ commutes with $y^{2}$. But $x$ also commutes with $1 = y^{3}$, and so $x$ commutes with $y^{3} (y^{2})^{-1} = y$. Therefore $x^{-1} = x^{y} = x$, or $x^{2} = 1$, and since $x^{9} = 1$, we have $x = x^{9} (x^{2})^{-4} = 1$, so that $Q$ turns out to be cyclic of order $3$, generated by $y$.

> I suspect that the intended relation might have been $x^{y} = y^{4}$ instead of $x^{y}= x^{-1}$.

Comment: yes, you are right but its a mistake in article. tank you. you help me.